# Urxvt: how to increase the amount of lines I can scroll back?

Tags: terminal-emulator, rxvt

In other terminal emulators you can usually control the amounts of lines you can scroll back, but it seems it's a fixed amount in Urxvt.

I thought the "saveLines" option controlled that but I tried changing it to a higher amount to no avail, the amount of lines displayed doesn't change no matter the amount.

Is there any way to increase the amount of lines I can scroll back?

Comment: Cannot reproduce your problem. I've started `urxvt -sl 200000`, then inside it I ran `seq 1 200000`, and I could it scroll back to 1. How did you set the 'saveLines' resource?

Comment: fwiw, `echo 'Rxvt.saveLines: 200000' | xrdb -override` and `urxvt -xrm 'Rxvt.saveLines: 200000` also work fine here.

Comment: `urxvt -sl 200000` actually worked out, thanks, none of your other options worked out for me though. I'll tweak my configs to always start urxvt with `-sl 200000`.

Comment: I set "saveLines" as `URxvt.saveLines:            20000` in .Xdefaults, much like the other options.

Comment: @mosvy can you post your comment as a reply so I can mark it as answered?

Comment: don't bother about that; maybe someone else comes along who has an idea why urxvt isn't picking up that option from the xresources. I'd also try `urxvt -xrm '*saveLines: 20000'`

Answer (score 0):

Add something like this to your `~/Xresources` file:

```bash
! lines buffer
URxvt.saveLines: 4096
```

Then make changes effective with:

```bash
xrdb ~/Xresources
```

Then open a new terminal and you should have 4096 lines of back buffer.